Clone table to different server without Linked connection
I have 3 tables on serverA that I want to clone over to serverB.  Right now I need to connect to a VPN to access serverA and another VPN to access serverB and they don't have connections to eachother.  What is the easiest way to clone this tables?

How much data is in each table?

not much rows less than 100 but alot of columns close to 100

Do you mean you want to just do a one-off copy, or you want to have a regular process that synchronises the tables between the two servers?

just clone the table one time

@Bigbob23 Note you should use @ and the username of the person you're replying to for them to be notified. I didn't realize you replied to me until I stumbled back in here.


not much rows less than 100...
What is the easiest way to clone this tables?

Because the tables are so small, and this is a one-off use case, I'd recommend just using SSMS 's built in Generate and Publish Scripts Wizard feature to script out the tables with their data:

You can use the Generate and Publish Scripts Wizard to create scripts for transferring a database between instances of the SQL Server Database Engine or Azure SQL Database. You can generate scripts for a database on an instance of the Database Engine in your local network, or from SQL Database. The generated scripts can be run on another instance of the Database Engine or SQL Database...You can create scripts for an entire database, or limit it to specific objects.

Just follow the linked docs on how to use the wizard and make sure when you get to the step with the Advanced options, that you change the option Types of data to script to the selection Schema and Data.

I already ran it but I used the flat file method the issue is it didn't save the col type, if I do this again might try this.

@Bigbob23 Yes, if you do it the way I said, as scripts for Schema and Data, then it'll preserve the entire table definition (columns and all).
